# Azure Logic Apps not inserting a row for each instance in Google sheet

Tags: azure, google-sheets-api, azure-logic-apps

I am using a form site- Cognito Forms. Multiple students can register per form. The following happens using Microsoft Azure Logic Apps: The form is linked to a webhook. For each student a new row should be inserted into a google sheet. When I look at the run data, the input and output data is correct and the correct number of rows are being created. However When I check the google sheet, sometimes only some of rows are being inserted and in no particular order.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: pls share your code of logic apps (or) the screenshot of the logic app workflow

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but maybe someone can still benefit from an answer. I think I had a similar problem and I was able to solve it by adding the rows sequentially.

I am assuming you are trying to add the rows using "For each". You can configure it to insert the rows sequentially by going to settings, switch concurrency control on, and set the degree of parallelism to 1.

My guess is that if you don't add the rows sequentially, several inserts hit the Google api at more or less the same time and some of the inserts overwrite other inserts.